# googleusercontent resize return wrong image

Tags: google-image-search, google-content-api

I have a google image: http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YCHiHLv3pCrzi1dK4CFPMkyxPddG8qjsjez-ufiqthPhnqI5XIG39xuXPp0H4Di1BZk-RrIiAyb1nhUOGlA

Tried resize this image by add the "s=PixelValue" in the end of URL.

Example :

http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YCHiHLv3pCrzi1dK4CFPMkyxPddG8qjsjez-ufiqthPhnqI5XIG39xuXPp0H4Di1BZk-RrIiAyb1nhUOGlA=s100 -> worked

http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YCHiHLv3pCrzi1dK4CFPMkyxPddG8qjsjez-ufiqthPhnqI5XIG39xuXPp0H4Di1BZk-RrIiAyb1nhUOGlA=s200 -> worked

http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YCHiHLv3pCrzi1dK4CFPMkyxPddG8qjsjez-ufiqthPhnqI5XIG39xuXPp0H4Di1BZk-RrIiAyb1nhUOGlA=s300 -> worked

But from s=600 :

http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YCHiHLv3pCrzi1dK4CFPMkyxPddG8qjsjez-ufiqthPhnqI5XIG39xuXPp0H4Di1BZk-RrIiAyb1nhUOGlA=s600 -> Google return wrong image, it's different image but same URL

Comment: It looks like the max is 512

Comment: @marian.vladoi example this image : http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/QJt2NbaFsB9sQXDPYoyIPHDCeBeTJdu6kHO9U5gFmguZRReAvEyTzboItVidqWNeT1QEpzruKLBPcF_W (512x454) but you still can resize to 1000px. 

http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/QJt2NbaFsB9sQXDPYoyIPHDCeBeTJdu6kHO9U5gFmguZRReAvEyTzboItVidqWNeT1QEpzruKLBPcF_W=s1000

Comment: Could you specify which tool did you use to upload the image and get that URL?

Comment: @Mayeru I am using this https://github.com/albertcht/python-gcs-image